VSCode randomly auto selecting text when i write
For the past 2-3 days, I’ve been facing a very annoying issue in Visual Studio Code.
Sometimes, in a completely random way, the editor starts automatically selecting the text I’m typing. I’ve tried several solutions:
Disabling all extensions
Reinstalling a different version of VS Code
Resetting all settings to their defaults
Unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.
I’m certain the problem does not come from my keyboard, as I do not experience this behavior in other editors.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.


Go to settings, search for "editor.selection" in the search bar and uncheck the "Editor: Selection Highlight" feature
